# Python urllib3 and how to handle cookie support?

Tags: python, urllib3

So I'm looking into [urllib3](http://code.google.com/p/urllib3/) because it has connection pooling and is thread safe (so performance is better, especially for crawling), but the documentation is... minimal to say the least. urllib2 has build_opener so something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import cookielib, urllib2
cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
r = opener.open("http://example.com/")
```

But urllib3 has no build_opener method, so the only way I have figured out so far is to manually put it in the header:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import urllib3
http_pool = urllib3.connection_from_url("http://example.com")
myheaders = {'Cookie':'some cookie data'}
r = http_pool.get_url("http://example.org/", headers=myheaders)
```

But I am hoping there is a better way and that one of you can tell me what it is. Also can someone tag this with "urllib3" please.

Comment: @bigredbob, tagged as you asked.  I've looked at urllib3's sources and it seems to have none of the tweaks and turns of urllib2, including `Opener` objects, so I doubt there's a magic wand for you. Let's hope it matures with time, as it's pretty unripe as of now!-)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're correct, there's no immediately better way to do this right now. I would be more than happy to accept a patch if you have a congruent improvement.

One thing to keep in mind, urllib3's HTTPConnectionPool is intended to be a "pool of connections" to a specific host, as opposed to a stateful client. In that context, it makes sense to keep the tracking of cookies outside of the actual pool.

- shazow (the author of urllib3)

Comment: If I knew how to patch this I would love to, but I'm not that good. It's good to know I'm not doing it wrong at least.

Answer (score 4):

Is there not a problem with multiple cookies?

Some servers return multiple Set-Cookie headers, but urllib3 stores the headers in a dict and a dict does not allow multiple entries with the same key.

httplib2 has a similar problem.

Or maybe not: it turns out that the readheaders method of the HTTPMessage class in the httplib package -- which both urllib3 and httplib2 use -- has the following comment:

> If multiple header fields with the same name occur, they are combined according to the rules in RFC 2616 sec 4.2:

```
    Appending each subsequent field-value to the first, each separated
    by a comma. The order in which header fields with the same field-name
    are received is significant to the interpretation of the combined
    field value.
```

So no headers are lost.

There is, however, a problem if there are commas within a header value. I have not yet figured out what is going on here, but from skimming RFC 2616 ("Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1") and RFC 2965 ("HTTP State Management Mechanism") I get the impression that any commas within a header value are supposed to be quoted.

Comment: RFC6265 says Set-Cookie has to be special cased to handle this.  httplib is not doing so in python 2 ... see http://bugs.python.org/issue1660009

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `'Cookie'` not `'Set-Cookie'`, `'Set-Cookie'` set by web server.

And Cookies are one of headers, so its nothing wrong with doing that way.

Comment: Yeah that was a typo, but my question still stands, I'd like a better way (i.e. using built-ins).

Answer (score 1):

Given a `CookieJar` and a `PoolManager`:

```
# A dummy Request used to hold request data in a form understood by CookieJar
dummy_request = urllib.request.Request(url, headers={"X-Example": "client-specified-header"})

# Add a Cookie header to dummy_request based on contents of the CookieJar
jar.add_cookie_header(dummy_request)

# Actually make the request with urllib3
response = pool_manager.request("GET", url, headers=dict(dummy_request.header_items()), redirect=False)

# Populate the CookieJar with any new cookies
jar.extract_cookies(response, dummy_request)
```

Note that it's important to disable redirects, because otherwise urllib3 will follow the redirects, disclosing any cookies intended for the original host to the redirect target hosts!

Answer (score 0):

You should use the requests library. It uses urllib3 but makes things like adding cookies trivial.

https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests

```
import requests
r1 = requests.get(url, cookies={'somename':'somevalue'})
print(r1.content)
```

Comment: Is this supposed to add a cookie to my browser? If so, what are some reasons it would not work? I tested this on my local website running on apache server, Windows 10, Python 2.75.

Comment: More to the point you'd use the `requests.Session` class, which manages cookies on behalf of the client.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a code like this:

```
def getHtml(url):
    http = urllib3.PoolManager()
    r = http.request('GET', url, headers={'User-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.16 Safari/537.36','Cookie':'cookie_name=cookie_value'})
    return r.data #HTML
```

You should replace cookie_name and cookie_value

Comment: I'll just use the requests library which lets you put the cookies right in the request and does propagate them.