# How to make a http request with cookies using urllib3 Python library?

Tags: python, http, cookies, httprequest, urllib3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python urllib3 and how to handle cookie support?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422922/python-urllib3-and-how-to-handle-cookie-support)

I am trying to retrieve source code from a webpage with an already issued cookie and write the source code to a txt file. If I remove the `cookies=cookie` portion I can retrieve the source code but I need to somehow send the cookie with the http request.

```
output = open('Filler.txt', 'w+')
http = urllib3.PoolManager()
cookie =('users' , '1597413515')
r = http.request('http://google.com' , 'GET' , cookies=cookie)
output.write(r.data)
output.close()
```

I get a KeyError: None

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the cookie to the header before sending the request. Have you seen [Python urllib3 and how to handle cookie support?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422922/python-urllib3-and-how-to-handle-cookie-support)