# urllib3 set cookie onto the browser

Tags: python, urllib3

In the scenario where the browser request the below python code to serve something from a webpage and the python program should be able set all the cookies issued by the host website, how to do the same using urllib3. also is urlib3 lib the right way to go?

The end goal is the cookie has to be set in the browser as issued by the host site

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import urllib3
http_pool = urllib3.connection_from_url("http://example.com")
r = http_pool.get_url("http://example.org/", headers="set the cookie as issued by the host site")
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python urllib3 and how to handle cookie support?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422922/python-urllib3-and-how-to-handle-cookie-support)