# Urllib3 HTTP Error 502: Bad Gateway

Tags: python, urllib3, bad-gateway

I am trying to scrape zk.fm in order to download music, but it's giving me some trouble. I'm using urllib3 to generate a response, but this always yields a Bad Gateway error. Accessing the website through a browser works perfectly fine.

This is my code (with a random fake user-agent). I'm trying to access "http://zk.fm/mp3/search?keywords=" followed by some keywords which indicate the song name and artist, for example "http://zk.fm/mp3/search?keywords=childish+gambino+heartbeat".

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from random import choice
import urllib3 

desktop_agents = ['Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36',
             'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36',
             'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36',
             'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_1) AppleWebKit/602.2.14 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0.1 Safari/602.2.14',
             'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36',
             'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.98 Safari/537.36',
             'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.98 Safari/537.36',
             'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36',
             'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36',
             'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0']
def random_headers():
    return {'User-Agent': choice(desktop_agents)}

ua = random_headers()
http = urllib3.PoolManager(10,headers=user_agent)
response = http.request('GET',"http://zk.fm/mp3/search? 
keywords=childish+gambino+heartbeat")
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.data)
```

Is there a way to work around the 502 Error, or is it out of my control?

Comment: If you visit the URL in a browser, you get this error... Until you visit the homepage of the site... Looks like there is some kind of restriction, like cookies.

Comment: Definitely cookies. I cleared them

Comment: Cookies indeed :). See below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to enable the persistence of cookies, then access, in order, the site home page followed by the search URL. I suggest (personally) python-requests, but it is up to you. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422922/python-urllib3-and-how-to-handle-cookie-support) for discussion.

I tested this by visiting the search page - error 502. visit home page - 200. visit search - 200. clear cookies and visit search again - 502. So it must be cookies that are the problem.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick! I created a persisting session using requests.Session(), after which I did a .post request to the home page, followed by a .get request to the search url.