# How do you use cookiejar with urllib3?

Tags: python, urllib3

How do you use [cookiejar](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.cookiejar.html) with urllib3?

According to [Python urllib3 and how to handle cookie support?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2422922/369450) from 2010 it wasn't supported then. However, in the change log for [urllib3](https://pypi.org/project/urllib3/) 1.22 (2017-07-20) there's mention of a compatibility fix for cookiejar.

> Fixed compatibility for cookiejar. (Issue #1229)

So it sounds like some support has been added. But I have been unable to find any mention about cookiejar or even cookies in urllib3's documentation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python urllib3 and how to handle cookie support?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422922/python-urllib3-and-how-to-handle-cookie-support)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the test suite](https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/blob/7c1d682db68fa8964b5d82e18d99cfdfad07e82b/test/test_compatibility.py#L3), `CookieJar`'s `extract_cookies` method can be used to populate a `CookieJar` from an instance of `urllib3`'s `HTTPResponse` class:

```
cookiejar.extract_cookies(response, request)
```